# How to copy tablespace from one database to another database in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, backup, restore, tablespaces, datafile

How to copy tablespace and datafiles from one database to another database in Oracle 11g in same server ?

Answer (score 3):

While copying a tablespace, it automatically includes data files and indexes associated with it. You need to make sure that tablespace is self contained.

1. Confirm that tablespace is self contained
   `execute DBMS_TTS.TRANSPORT_SET_CHECK('<TABLESPACENAME>', true);`
2. Use the *TRANSPORT_SET_VIOLATIONS* view to check if any violations condition  exists
   `select * from TRANSPORT_SET_VIOLATIONS;`
   if any exist then fix them.
3. Make the tablespace read only
   `alter tablespace <TABLESPACENAME> read only;`
4. Use `EXPDP COMMAND` to export the tablespace:

   ```
   EXPDP USERNAME/PASSWORD DIRECTORY=DIRECTORYNAME DUMPFILE=DUMPFILE.DMP
   LOGFILE=ERROR.LOG TRANSPORT_TABLESPACE=TABLESPACENAME
   ```

   (You should have the rights necessary to execute `IMPDP/EXPDP` command and access rights to directory objects which map to the OS folder.)
5. Copy the datafiles to the target database using `ftp` or `scp` or somt other filesystem utility.
6. Make the tablespace `READ WRITE` again in the source database
7. Use `IMPDP` command to import it into target database:

   ```
   IMPDP USERNAME/PASSWORD DIRECTORY=DIRECTORYNAME DUMPFILE=DUMPFILENAME.DMP 
   LOGFILE=ERROR.LOG
   ```
8. Check logfile for errors, if any
9. Make the tablespace read write in the target database:

   ```
   ALTER TABLESPACE <TABLESPACENAME> READ WRITE
   ```

Comment: If my tablesize is large and I am not having a space to export that file then what should I do ?

Comment: @Delta: It seems that you assume that the datafiles are included in the export file, That is wrong. You have to copy the data files.

Comment: @Paresh: The datafile  is rather small because it contains only the metadata

Comment: @miracle173 But my tablespace size is in GB and I don't have that much space is current drive so what should I do (as I think EXPDUMP will required equal amount of memory as tablespace size)?

Comment: @Paresh: No, that is wrong. The export file is small if you do as tranportable tablespace export.

Comment: @Paresh: Another option you have is to make an import t using a database link. Then all data is sent over the link directly from the source database to the target database abd no dumpfile is needed at all.